# Does 5G affect your physics experiment?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, estimation, microwaves, noise

Our institution wants to lease a nearby roof for a 5G mast. Has anyone experienced the installation and operation of telecoms infrastructure - particularly 5G - significantly affecting physics experiments that involve frequencies in the microwave range?

Comment: If you are anywhere near a commercial airport (10+ miles), the radar will definitely upset sensitive equipment. It doesn't even have to be sensitive to the radar frequencies. The non-linearity of opamp input stages is perfectly enough to give you tens, if not hundreds of nV of bursts every time the radar cone hits the building. 5G might actually work in your favor because of the tight beam profiles, though.. if you can stay out of them.